# How to find the app downloaded date in appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, itunes

I want to know the downloaded date for particular app from appstore?. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way.

However you can do by saving the first download date in keychain, or some other file and whenever you want to know retrieve it back.

EDIT:

And all the keychains are stored in your device even after removing the app. Consider you removed the app and again downloaded it, your keychain will be intact with the very-first date and time.

Comment: How do you find the download date ? Because the first launch can happen many days after the download.

Comment: Now this is extreme case... you purchase an app and never uses it !!!